# table-layout с исключением одной колонки

Tags: html, css, css3

У меня есть динамическая таблица, с одним полем. При нажатии кнопки "добавить" добавляется еще один `<tr>` и тд. на первом `<tr>` у меня нет кнопки "удалить" но при добавлении следующих, эта кнопка появляется. Для таблицы я использую `table-layout` поскольку внутри может быть `select` который может быть длинным и портить всю таблицу и `table-layout` меня вполне устраивает, но вот когда я добавляю следующее поле и появляется мелкая кнопка "удалить" - она тоже идет как ячейка (`td`) и соответственно ее размер становиться таким же как и размер других ячеек. я пробовал делать на `table table-layout:fixed; width:100%`, а на ячейку `width:5%`, но это не помогло, также как и просто установление ширины. Подскажите как сделать ее поменьше? [Пример плнкр](https://plnkr.co/edit/Esp47nA6Jksbeq7Jxi9j?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант вышло пара вариантов для решения вопроса:

1. добавить стили в css:

   `table, tr, td:nth-child(-1) {
        width: auto;
        border:none;
        margin: 1px;
   }`

   2. добавить в `<th>` одну дополнительную колонку, которую можно скрыть прибавив стиль `border-color:transparent` и добавив установленную ширину например `width:30px` и тогда все ячейки будут по размерам одинаковы за исключением последней. Плюс еще в том что не зависимо от кол-ва динамически добавившихся колонок - последняя будет выделена именно под нужную ширину. это тоже работает но не так красиво выходит :)

Answer (score 0):

После тега **< table >** добавьте описание колонок. Для каждой колонки вы можете задать ее ширину.

```
<table>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col width="30">
</table>
```

Comment: колонки динамически также подгружаются и угадать сколько их будет невозможно(

Comment: вы же используете ангуляр! эти элементы тоже динамически можно создавать